# Dependency injection in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function createCoffee that accepts a function argument called knowHow

```
    function createCoffee(knowHow){
var x=new knowHow(coffee,beans,milk,sugar);
knowHow.create();
}
```

This is so that I can have different knowHow for how to create the coffee.

Then I write a sample knowHow function

```
    var x=function oneWay(a,b,c,d){
console.log(a+b+c+d)
};
```

I pass x to createCoffee

Then

```
a=5;b=1;c=2;d=2;

createCoffee(x);
```

This should createCoffee according to the specified knowHow.

I expected that the result would be logging in the sum of the variables. Does it have something to do with variable scope.

Is the example logically sound. How can I specify the variables in the oneWay(...) function

Comment: there is no function `create` in your var x. Also, naming the function `oneWay` is not necessary. You should search `prototypes` and objet oriented javascript, too

Comment: Only `createCoffee` knows those variables `coffee`, `beans`, `milk` and `sugar`? You don't seem to have defined them anywhere. Defining `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` somewhere outside of `oneWay` doesn't have any effects.

Comment: Are you expecting a,b,c,d to be captured whenever you set `var x=func...`?

Comment: When posting JavaScript questions it's usually a good idea to add a jsFiddle so that people can more easily see what your code does exactly. Have a look at jsfiddle.net :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of initializing a,b,c,d, do this:

```
var coffee=5, beans=1, milk=2, sugar=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I solved my objective in the following way ....

```
function coffeeMaker(knowHow,coffee,milk,sugar){
    knowHow.create(coffee,milk,sugar);
}

var x={create: function oneWay(a,b,c){
    console.log(a+b+c);
}};

coffeeMaker(x,2,3,4);
```

I wanted to make it so that I could do the program according to interface thing as is done in Java.

In Java you can pass reference to an interface and you can have different implementations.
I wanted to achieve the same thing.

In this I can change the knowHow and plug it into the coffeeMaker.

It looks redundant in the present case but when there are like 10 behaviors associated with an object then it becomes useful. I am drawing on the Strategy design pattern for this.